# Spring jdbcTemplate is stuck at Executing prepared SQL query

Tags: java, spring, oracle, java-11, jdbctemplate

I am having an issue with spring jdbcTemplate. It used to work fine, but now it doesn't return any value neither error message it gets stuck saying `"DEBUG | \[main\] | org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate:query(711) | Executing prepared SQL query"`,

I tried using namedParameterJDBCTemplate and JDBCTemplate

Please find below my Hikari configuration  :

```xml
<bean id="HikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="select 1 from dual" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${some_db_name}" />
    <property name="username" value="${some_db_username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${some_db_password}" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="50"/>
    <property name="minimumIdle" value="2" />
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="600000"/>
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="v$session.program">some_program</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>undefined</beans>
```

Please find below the JDBC template configuration :

```xml
<bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="TransactionManager" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="OracleDataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="oraJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <ref bean="OracleDataSource" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="fetchSize" value="10000" />
    <property name="queryTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>
<bean id="NamedJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="oraJdbcTemplate" />
</bean>
<bean id="OracleDataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="HikariConfig" />
</bean>
<bean id="OracleDatasource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="HikariConfig" />
</bean>
```

I tried multiple ways to solve this problem but could not resolve it.
Also, note that when I run this locally, it is working, but when the application runs in UAT (Linux) it gets stuck and when I run the query in SQL, I am getting results (There are only 4 results in the database for the query). ojdbc10 is being used.

Please find logs below :

`2023-05-17 15:20:16,341 | DEBUG | [main] | org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils:doGetConnection(116) | Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource 2023-05-17 15:20:17,344 | DEBUG | [main] | somePackage.someClass:someMethod(99) | [someMethod] deleteMakerQuery ::`

```
            --some query---
```

`2023-05-17 15:20:17,344 | DEBUG | [main] | somePackage.someClass:someMethod(100) | [someMethod] paramMap :: {someParms=134975, someParms=1, someParms=134975} 2023-05-17 15:20:17,344 | DEBUG | [main] | org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate:query(711) | Executing prepared SQL query`